# Get precision of a half type over 1/256

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, precision, cg

I'm making a Unity image shader, and I have the following problem:

I calculate the color values to half3-s (1*half for each channel), and on some devices with a 256 (8bit) deep channel gradient is not so smooth enough.

[image: One channel of a gradient:]

Please, check my picture of the problem.

To make it smooth, I want to get the channel precision over 1/256 to another half value between 0 and 1. (After that I want to calculate a random noise value (0 or 1) depended on the extra precision.)

I tried this:

```c#
float greenPrecision = (backColor.g * 256) % 1;
```

But it's not precise enough. (The borders of the color changes do not fit perfectly.)

[image: greenPrecision value looks like this.]

Comment: #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_nicest

Comment: In theory it might help

Comment: It appears that your problem can be solved by _dithering_; I am not familiar with Unity to explain further, though.